# $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle over compact base

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, classifying-spaces

1) Is it possible to construct a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle $P\to B$ where $B$ is a proper variety and $P$ is not $\mathbb{P}(V)$ for a rank 2 vector bundle $V\to B$?

If we drop the properness assumption on $B$, I only know of a couple examples.

2) Does a Zariski locally trivial projective bundle come from the projectivization of a vector bundle? (This feels like it should be standard, but I'm ignorant.)

Comment: The simplest examples might be Severi-Brauer varieties over an Abelian surface $A$ constructed as symbol algebras associated to a pair of $\mathbb{Z}/\ell\mathbb{Z}$-linearly independent elements of $H^1(A;\mathbb{Z}/\ell\mathbb{Z})$.  There are many other examples.  In some sense, constructing examples like this is the purpose of my article with de Jong, "Discriminant avoidance ..."

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Severi-Brauer_variety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) There are many examples. As abx mentioned, they are called Severi-Brauer varieties, and they are related to 2-torsion classes in the Brauer group of $B$. If you want a geometric construction, to get a relatively simple example consider a general cubic 4-fold $X \subset \mathbb{P}^5$ containing a plane $\Pi \subset X$. Let $F(X)$ be the Hilbert scheme of lines on $X$ and 
$$
P \subset F(X)
$$
be the closure of the locus of lines in $X$ that intersect $\Pi$ but are not contained in $\Pi$. Then it has a structure of a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle over $B$, which is the double covering of $\mathbb{P}^2$ branched over a sextic curve (thus $B$ is a K3-surface).

2) This is true, only if $B$ is smooth. For singular surfaces there are counterexamples. The simplest I know is for 
$$
B = (\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1)/(\mathbb{Z}/2),
$$
where the group acts diagonally, and nontrivially on each factor.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a reference for 2)? (Where one would use $B$ is smooth and what bundle you are creating over $(\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1)/(\mathbb{Z}/2)$?)

Comment: You can start with Bright, Martin. Brauer groups of singular del Pezzo surfaces. Michigan Math. J. 62 (2013), no. 3, 657--664.

Comment: When you consider in example 2) your 'diagonal action' by $\mathbb{Z}/2$ on
$\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ by which action of 
$\mathbb{Z}/2$ on a single factor $\mathbb{P}^1$ is it induced
in your example? Is this a certain well known action which you
assume to be 'canonical' enough not require the neccessarity to write in down explicitely or do you consider a not specified 'abstract' 
action by $\mathbb{Z}/2$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$ which is just required to 
be nontrivial, but otherwise arbitrary?

Comment: @IsaktheXI: All (nontrivial) $\mathbb{Z}/2$-actions on $\mathbb{P}^1$ are conjugate in the authomorphisms group, so it does not matter which one you consider. The simplest is given by $(x:y) \mapsto (x:-y)$.

Comment: @BenC: No, $B$ is not a quadratic cone. In fact, it has 4 singular points (corresponding to 4 fixed points of $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action on $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$), and its minimal resolution of singularities is a weak del Pezzo surface of degree 4 (blowup of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at 5 points not in general position). The existence of a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle over $B$ with the prescribed properties follows from the paper of M. Bright cited above.

Comment: @Sasha you're absolutely right my mistake.